# Sending HttpSession from one controller to another in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am redirecting my request from one controller to another, but while doing that I am loosing my session attributes. But I want to use the session only so that I can verify if user is logged in or not. Whole condition is explained below:

Login.jsp
This is the page in which user gives its username and password and the request goes to "LoginController" .

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
  ${loginError }
  <h1>Login Details</h1>

  <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/login" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="userId" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginController.java
As the action was "login" using post method so the request maps to "verifyLogin()" method.

I have checked for the customer name it is coming after calling "loginCustomer()" method of "CustomerService" class.

But when I set it in session attributes and redirect it to url which match up to "HomeController" method I am losing that session attributes their.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/login")
public class LoginController {

  @Autowired
  private CustomerService customerService;

  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String showLoginForm(){

    return "login";
  }

  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String verifyLogin(@RequestParam String userId, @RequestParam String password, HttpSession session, Model model){

    Customer customer = customerService.loginCustomer(userId, password);
    if(customer==null){
        model.addAttribute("loginError", "Username or password is not correct");
        return "login";
    }
    session.addAttribute("loggedInUser", customer);
    return "redirect:/";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="logout", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String logoutUser(HttpSession session){

    session.removeAttribute("loggedInUser");
    return "login";
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ModelAndView handleException(){

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("loginError", "Usrname or password is not correct");
    mav.setViewName("login");
    return mav;
  }
}
```

HomeController.java
The request mapped to "home()" method. This method is also called when application loads up, and when user logged in correctly then also it is called.

Here in this method I am loosing my session attribute, but I want it in the page were this method maps i.e. home.jsp the return value of this method.

As session attribute is not available in this method so its not available in the home.jsp page also.
Please help.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

  @Autowired
  private ProductService productService;
  @Autowired
  private CategoryService categoryService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String home(Model model) {

    List<Product> products = productService.getFeaturedProducts();
    List<Category> categories = categoryService.getAllCategories();
    model.addAttribute("featuredProduct", products);
    model.addAttribute("categories",categories);

    return "home";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go for `RedirectAttributes`.

```
redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("loggedInUser", customer);
```

Further reading: -[Flash Attribute](http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.in/2012/02/spring-mvc-flash-attributes.html)

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that your session Id cookie might get lost between login and next page. (could be because the Web app is configured not to use cookies or the cookie is set for the wrong domain)

To verify check in your browser that: 
After successful login the server sets the session cookie for the current host (chrome or Firefox Dev tools can help you here) 
And also that your Browser sends the same cookie in the next request for the homepage.

If this does not help please also include the set cookie and the cookie headers in your reply

Answer (score 0):

I've used session with the help plain old `HttpServletRequest request` and that seemed to serve the purpose for me.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String verifyLogin(@RequestParam String userId, @RequestParam String password, HttpServletRequest request, Model model){

   Customer customer = customerService.loginCustomer(userId, password);
   HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
   if (session == null) {
       session = request.getSession();
   }
   if(customer==null){
       model.addAttribute("loginError", "Username or password is not correct");
       return "login";
   }
   session.addAttribute("loggedInUser", customer);
   return "redirect:/";
}
```

By this way, you can access the session values through the request object in both your controller and jsp page.